# How the last line of following recursive program is working?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I was studying Linked List and then I found a code for reversing the Linked List recursively. Here is the C++ code.

```
void recursiveReverse(node*& head)
{
  node* first;
  node* rest;

/* checking for an empty list */
  if (head == NULL)
   return;   

  first = head;  
  rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
  if (rest == NULL)
   return;   

  recursiveReverse(rest);
  first->next->next  = first;  
  first->next  = NULL;          

/* fix the head pointer */
  head = rest;              
}
```

I understood the whole code except the last line. Because according to me, the rest pointer is also updated similarly as the first pointer during unwinding of the recursion and therefore, at the end of this code, the head will not point to the last node.

Here's my interpretation of the following code.

Let's take a Linked List 1 -> 2 -> 3.

1. Initially, first will store the address of the head node and rest
   will contain the address of the node 2.
2. Now, since rest is not NULL, therefore, recursiveReverse(rest) will be called.
3. Now, first will point to node 2 and rest will point to node 3.
4. Again, rest is not NULL, therefore, recursiveReverse(rest) will be called.
5. Now, first will point to node 3 and rest will contain NULL.
6. After that, the recursion will start unwinding and first will be back to node 2 and the rest will be back to node 3.
7. Now, the statement **first -> next -> next = first;** will cause the next part of node 3 to point to node 2 and the Linked List will become **1 -> 2 <- 3**. The next part of node 2 will contain NULL and since **head = rest**, therefore, head will also point to last node as the rest pointer.
8. After that, first will point to node 1 and the statement **first -> next -> next = first;** will cause the next part of node 2 to point to node 1 and the Linked List will become **1 <- 2 <- 3**. The next part of the node 1 will contain NULL and the statement **head = rest** will cause the head to point to node 2 and not the node 3 since, the rest (which is first -> next) is currently at node 2.

Can anyone please explain where I am wrong in interpreting this code?

Comment: You could step through line-by-line with a debugger to find out what really happens.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I tried line-by-line by debugging and I get to know that rest is not changing but it is fixed. But I am not able to find out the reason why it is happening and that's why, I've put up this question here.

Comment: Try writing state of list on paper before function call, and every time state of list changes while step through line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are other misinterpretations, but I assume that the basic one concerns your interpretation "the statement head = rest will cause the head to point to node 2 and not the node 3 since, the rest (which is first -> next) is currently at node 2".

At the end, `head` will point to the last node of the initial list. Let's consider a simplified/shortened portion of your code:

```
rest  = head->next;

if (rest == NULL)  // end of list reached; head points tho the last node 
   return;

recursiveReverse(rest);  // if the end is not reached, go forward with the next node (i.e. the value of head->next

head = rest;    // reset head to the (shared) value of rest.
```

This is because statement `recursiveReverse(rest)` will be called again and again until `head->next` will be `NULL`, i.e. the end of the list is reached. The very last run of `recursiveReverse` returns because `head->next == NULL`, and in the caller, variable `rest` points to the last node. 
Now note that "rest" is shared among all the calls to `recursiveReverse`, as it is passed by reference. So statement `head = rest` will be called for every instance of `recursiveReverse` called so far, but - as `rest` is shared among all the calls and is not changed after the recursive calls - statement `head = rest` will assign the `head` always to the same value of `rest`, which remains the one pointing to the last node.

Puh - hope this is comprehensive.

Anyway, doing recursive functions with parameters passed by reference is usually hard to understand; Typically things become easier when recursive functions manage their private states but use the return value to coordinate the results. If you arrange the code such that you have `node* reverseRecursive(node *current)`, your code will become easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in step 8. you forgot that `head` in `void recursiveReverse(node*& head)` is a reference. So when you recursively call `recursiveReverse(rest);` then `rest` is passed by reference. That means that, when inside the recursion, `head` is a reference to the `rest` variable in the calling function. Therefore when it was changed to point to `3` inside the recursion then `rest` in the calling function was also changed.

If this sounds confusing then drawing up the local variables on the stack might help:

1) Initially, `head` will be a reference to the pointer to the node passed to the function, `first` will store the address of the head node and `rest` will contain the address of the node 2.

The stack will look like this (only showing local variables and ignoring whatever was already there when calling the function):

```
====================================
head:     reference to original head
first:    node 1
rest:     node 2
```

2) Now, since rest is not `NULL`, `recursiveReverse(rest)` will be called.

3) Now, `head` will reference `rest` in the calling  function, `first` will point to node 2 and `rest` will point to node 3.
The stack will look like this:

```
====================================
head:     reference to original head
first:    node 1
rest:     node 2      <---------------+
====================================  |
head:     reference to ---------------+
first:    node 2
rest:     node 3
```

4) Again, rest is not `NULL`, therefore `recursiveReverse(rest)` will be called.

5) Now, `head` will reference `rest` in the last calling function, `first` will point to node 3 and `rest` will contain `NULL`.
The stack will look like this:

```
====================================
head:     reference to original head
first:    node 1
rest:     node 2      <---------------+
====================================  |
head:     reference to ---------------+
first:    node 2
rest:     node 3      <---------------+
====================================  |
head:     reference to ---------------+
first:    node 3
rest:     NULL
```

6) Since `rest` is `NULL` we just return and the stack is back to this:

```
====================================
head:     reference to original head
first:    node 1
rest:     node 2      <---------------+
====================================  |
head:     reference to ---------------+
first:    node 2
rest:     node 3
```

7) Now, the statement `first->next->next = first;` will cause the `next` part of node 3 to point to node 2 and the Linked List will become `1 -> 2 <- 3`. The next part of node 2 will contain `NULL`. Since `head` is a reference to `rest` **in the calling function** then `head = rest` will make the `rest` **referenced by `head`** to point to the same node as the local `rest`:

```
====================================
head:     reference to original head
first:    node 1
rest:     node 3      <---------------+ (head = rest; made *this* rest
====================================  |  be equal to the *local* rest)
head:     reference to ---------------+
first:    node 2
rest:     node 3
```

8) After that, we return and `first` will again point to node 1 and the statement `first->next->next = first;` will cause the next part of node 2 to point to node 1 and the Linked List will become `1 <- 2 <- 3`. The next part of the node 1 will contain `NULL` and the statement `head = rest` will cause the pointer referenced by `head` to point to node 3 since `rest` was changed to point to node 3 in step 7.

Answer (score 0):

We beginners should help each other.:)

In my opinion it is not easy to understand how the function works for such beginners as we.

So it is better to figure out its work using schemes.

If the list either does not contain nodes or contains only one node then there is nothing to reverse.

This code snippet corresponds to this conclusion.

```
/* checking for an empty list */
  if (head == NULL)
   return;   

  first = head;  
  rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
  if (rest == NULL)
   return;
```

Now let's assume that the list contains exactly two nodes. In this case it looks like

```
--------    ----------    ----------------   
| head | -> |   A  |B| -> |   B  |nullptr|
--------    ----------    ----------------
```

This list is split into the following parts the following way

```
--------    ----------
| head | -> |   A  |B|
--------    ----------


--------    ----------
| first| -> |   A  |B|
--------    ----------

--------    ----------------   
| rest | -> |   B  |nullptr|
--------    ----------------
```

This code snippet corresponds to this conclusion

```
first = head;  
rest  = first->next;
```

Now the function calls itself recursively

```
recursiveReverse(rest);
```

In fact it is called for this new list

```
--------    ----------------   
| rest | -> |   B  |nullptr|
--------    ----------------
```

as this new list contains only one node then the function just returns.

As the original list must be reversed then the `head` must contain the value of `rest` that is the `head` must point to the node `"B"`

This code snippet corresponds to this conclusion

```
head = rest;
```

However in this case we will get

```
--------    ----------------   
| head | -> |   B  |nullptr|
--------    ----------------
```

But this list contains only one node `"B"`. So before executing this statement

```
head = rest;
```

we need to append the list with the node `"A"`.

As we have that the pointer `first` points to the node `"A"`

```
--------    ----------
| first| -> |   A  |B|
--------    ----------
```

then we can do the following

```
first->next->next  = first;
```

that results in

```
--------     ----------    -----------   
| first | -> |   A  |B| -> |   B  | A|
--------     ----------    -----------
```

that is on the other hand we have

```
--------    ----------    -----------   
| rest | -> |   B  |A| -> |   A  | B|
--------    ----------    -----------
```

and then after this statement

```
first->next  = NULL;
```

we will get

```
--------     ----------------  | -----------   
| first | -> |   A  |nullptr|  | |   B  | A|-----------
--------     ----------------  | -----------          |
                                     ^                V
--------                             |             -----------------   
| rest | ----------------------------              |   A  | nullptr|
--------                                           -----------------
```

Now it is indeed time to call the statement

```
head = rest;
```

and we will get

```
--------     ----------------  | -----------   
| first | -> |   A  |nullptr|  | |   B  | A|-----------
--------     ----------------  | -----------          |
                                     ^                V
--------                             |             -----------------   
| head | ----------------------------              |   A  | nullptr|
--------                                           -----------------
```

That is the list is reversed.

If the list contains more than two nodes then after splitting the original list the pointer `first` will point to the first node of the original list that has to be the last node in the reversed list. In turn this first node will point to the next node that in the reversed list will be the last node.

Using this code snippet

```
first->next->next  = first;  
first->next  = NULL;
```

we can place it after the last node in the reversed list. And all we need to do is to set the `head` to the value stored in the pointer `rest` because the pointer `rest` is the head of the reversed list to which the node pointed to by the pointer `first` is appended.

```
head = rest;
```

That is all.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int value;
    node *next;
};

void push( node * &head, int value )
{
    head = new node { value, head };
}

std::ostream & out( node * const &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->value << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

void recursiveReverse( node * &head )
{
    if ( head != nullptr && head->next != nullptr )
    {
        node *first = head;
        node *rest  = head->next;


        recursiveReverse( rest );


        first->next->next  = first;  
        first->next  = nullptr;          

        head = rest;
    }       
}

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int value = 0; value < N; value++ )
    {
        push( head, value );
    }

    out( head ) << std::endl;

    recursiveReverse( head );

    out( head ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```